# zsh exec error & .out doesn't exist- Can't find a way to run C programs

Tags: c, linux, gcc

As the title says, I've been trying to run C/C++ code on my Kali machine in vain. I used to be in Windows and had the exact same problem. (.exe doesn't exist)

I don't remember the steps exactly but I know I uninstalled/installed mingw, checked the env variables, installed VS Code again and eventually literally dualbooted Kali Linux to sort of have a fresh start (I might have messed with Windows so I wanted to exclude this option.)

[My two attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQk1z.png)

[The json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGIlh.png)

Comment: First of all, please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: VSCode takes a lot of work to set up correctly. You seem to have just installed it and are expecting it to work 'out of the box'. Suggest you read the documentation and follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 1):

Who told you to use the `-c` option when you build? That creates an *object* file, which then needs to be *linked* to create the final executable.

Normally the executable flag will be set on the program file automatically, that you need to call `chmod` (chmod u+x executable) should be seen as an indicator that you're doing something wrong.

So the simple solution is to not use the `-c` option when building executable files:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
```

Alternatively you can create the object file and then link it:

```
$ gcc -c test.c
$ gcc test.o -o test
```

---

Unfortunately many environments tend to hide this, which means it's hard to know what's going on and how building C and C++ code really works.

I suggest you take some time to find and read a few tutorials about building from command-line, and how to create makefiles to build project using multiple source files. That will help you understand what's done in the background when your IDE or editor build for you.

This is especially needed when using editors like VSCode, which doesn't really have this functionality built-in, and you need to know the commands and options to build your projects to be able to modify the configuration files properly.